# Handling iOS errors while app moves to background process

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working on an Cordova mobile app, currently targets iOS platform. I would like to know how to handle errors when the user quit the app abruptly on middle by pressing the Home button. Let'say the user has clicked a button that navigates the file-system, read a file, encrypts the content and save into a different location. In the middle of the process the user has clicked the Home button and so the app has moved to background. Can I expect all the operations will complete even-though the app has moved to background or do I need to handle these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there are two things you need to know:

1) iOS will not perform background operations unless you explicitly tell it to do so, so in the case you described, iOS would just cancel the actions that are currently active in your app. However, you have the chance to perform some operation between the point in time where the user pressed the home button and the point in time where the app actually changed its status from active to not being active. This can be done in the `AppDelegate`, since this is the component that controls the *lifecycle* of your app. The method you use here is `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`, this gets called before your app enters the background, from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:):

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move
>   from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of
>   temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS
>   message) or when the user quits the app and it begins the transition
>   to the background state. An app in the inactive state continues to run
>   but does not dispatch incoming events to responders.

So, this would be the place to either cancel the current action or save the current state so that it can be restored later.

2) iOS allows for multi tasking, but its quite tricky and only allowed in certain cases. This means you can not perform random operations while your app is in the background.
Some of these cases are:

**Core Location Update:** If you are using Core Location in your app, your app can receive updates on when the GPS position of the device changes and gets the chance to perform some operations in the background based on the new GPS data

**Voice Over IP:** The app provides Voice-over-IP services. Apps with this key are automatically launched after system boot so that the app can reestablish VoIP services. Apps with this key are also allowed to play background audio. ([from the Apple Programming Guide on Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html))

**Background fetches:** With background fetches you can perform network requests on a regular basis, however you are still not able to perform the operations at points in time that you can precisely specify, you can rather tell iOS that you want to perform network requests in regular intervals and iOS will schedule the requests for you. [Here is an excellent read on background fetches](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html).

Hope it helps!